# Cannot read property 'params' of undefined while retrieving the data by id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i have to retrieve location info by calling the job id. I have created the action and reducer for that. While calling the action into component i am getting this error. Please help me i am new to this.

action.js

```
export const retrieveLocations = (jobId) =>(dispatch) => {
  return axios.get(urlLoc+'/jobs/'+jobId).then(res => {
          dispatch({
          type: RETRIEVE_LOCATION,
          payload: res.data.job.basicDetails
      });
  });
};
```

reducer:

```
case 'RETRIEVE_LOCATION':
            return{
                ...state,
                conLocations:action.payload
            }
```

ConfiguredLocation.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../stores/store';
import {removeLocation,retrieveLocations} from '../../actions/locationActions';
import {removeAllLocation} from '../../actions/locationActions'

let _labels;

class ConfiguredLocation extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let {jobId} = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.retrieveLocations(jobId);
    }

    handleRemove(mruCode){
        return this.props.removeLocation(mruCode);
    }

    clearall (){
       return this.props.removeAllLocation()
    }

    render(){
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        const {conLocations} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="col-padding">
              <div className="pos-div"><h3>Configured Location</h3><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>{this.clearall()}}>Remove all location</button></div><hr/>
               <table className="table">
                    <tbody>
                        {conLocations.map((loct,index)=><tr key={index}>
                           <td><h5>{loct.mruCode} - {_labels[loct.division]} - {loct.country}</h5></td>
                           <td className="text-right"><button type="button" className ="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={()=>{this.props.removeLocation(loct.mruCode)}}>
                               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        conLocations: state.locationRed.conLocations
    };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
      return{
          retrieveLocations:(jobId)=>{dispatch(retrieveLocations(jobId))},
          removeLocation: (mruCode)=>{dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode))},
          removeAllLocation: () =>{dispatch(removeAllLocation())}
      };
  };


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ConfiguredLocation);
```

I have missed something in component. componentDidMount()is having some issue. Will you please give me some suggestion to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

How you are passing jobId ?
You have to define in routing like this : 
then you can access it from `this.props.match.params.jobId`

Comment: will you please elaborate that? where i have to define that?

Comment: First you have to define this route in routing file : <Route path="ConfiguredLocation/:jobId" component={ConfiguredLocation}>
and then you can access jobId in ConfiguredLocation component using this.props.match.params.jobId

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `<ConfiguredLocation>` is rendered inside `<Route>`, or use `withRouter()` 
More info:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/match and
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach:

- install react-router-dom by `npm install --save react-router-dom` if you have not already installed it
- in `ConfiguredLocation.jsx` import `withRouter` and wrap `ConfiguredLocation` like this `withRouter(ConfiguredLocation)`

`ConfiguredLocation.jsx` should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// add the import bellow
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import store from '../../stores/store';
import {removeLocation,retrieveLocations} from '../../actions/locationActions';
import {removeAllLocation} from '../../actions/locationActions'

let _labels;

class ConfiguredLocation extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let {jobId} = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.retrieveLocations(jobId);
    }

    handleRemove(mruCode){
        return this.props.removeLocation(mruCode);
    }

    clearall (){
       return this.props.removeAllLocation()
    }

    render(){
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        const {conLocations} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className="col-padding">
              <div className="pos-div"><h3>Configured Location</h3><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>{this.clearall()}}>Remove all location</button></div><hr/>
               <table className="table">
                    <tbody>
                        {conLocations.map((loct,index)=><tr key={index}>
                           <td><h5>{loct.mruCode} - {_labels[loct.division]} - {loct.country}</h5></td>
                           <td className="text-right"><button type="button" className ="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={()=>{this.props.removeLocation(loct.mruCode)}}>
                               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        conLocations: state.locationRed.conLocations
    };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
      return{
          retrieveLocations:(jobId)=>{dispatch(retrieveLocations(jobId))},
          removeLocation: (mruCode)=>{dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode))},
          removeAllLocation: () =>{dispatch(removeAllLocation())}
      };
  };


// export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ConfiguredLocation);
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(ConfiguredLocation));
```